# c# WinForms TextBox_Leave

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a small problem. I have a TextBox myTxt. I set the myTxt_Leave event to check the database if input value already exists. If value exists, I display a MessageBox and set myTxt.Focus(). That wont let user to leave this TextBox, until another value (which does not exist in the database) is input.

But here is the catch...I would like to allow user to click on Cancel button on the form even if the value does not change. Is that possible?
Hope someone understands what I wanted to tell.

Thank you for any help.

EDIT:
I decided to change the interface a little. I put red label under the textbox "Value already exists" and disabled the Submit button until the value is correct.

But still, I'm curious if solution for my previous problem is possible?

Comment: what is happening when you try to click cancel button?

Comment: nothing, focus is set back to the textbox, so when I try to click the cancel button, it retriggers the myTxt_Leave() event. I changed the interface a litle - I put a red label under the txtbox and disabled the submit button and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of binding the event to the Leave interaction, just Highlight the box in red and disable the submit.  When the when the error is resolved or the action is cancelled, clear the red / disabled submit button.

Comment: Yea, I thought about it already and decided to put a label under the textbox with text "value already exists" in red. Will also disable the submit button. Thnx for the idea.